# What's the size limit per file on VSTS hosted git?

Tags: azure-devops

Wondering what the size limit is per file in a VSTS hosted git repo, before you have to switch to use LFS instead.

Thanks

Comment: this question should be on a tfs/git stackoverflow site

Comment: Hmm... I just followed the link at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/user-guide/provide-feedback which sent here with VSTS tag

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft limit activity by the resources consumed rather than a straight filesize limit and, since large files in a repo use more resources to process than in LFS, the limit is lower. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/rate-limits