# What are the VSTS repository storage limits

Tags: azure-devops

Our Dev's are asking what are the limitations placed on repositories and I am not finding any solid information. I have found some posts saying it is "basically" unlimited.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the size limit per file on VSTS hosted git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709991/whats-the-size-limit-per-file-on-vsts-hosted-git)

Answer (score -1):

Based on this blog: [How much data can you put on VSOnline?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2013/11/20/how-much-data-can-you-put-on-vsonline/) It’s based on the Blog store and Meta-data store (SQL azure database) and they are increasing, two years ago, the size can be 6.6TB -31.5TB (check the comment)